# Derivative Hermite Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a question regarding one step in a proof I'm reading:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \frac{d^m}{dx^m}e^{\frac{1}{2}(x-ik)^2}dx = i^m\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \frac{d^m}{dk^m}e^{\frac{1}{2}(x-ik)^2}dx$$

I don't see how this step works.

Comment: are you correct about $i^m$? Shouldn't be $(-i)^m$?

Comment: Ok, let's assume it is $(-i)^m$. How would I get that result?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\frac{1}{2}(x-ik)^2})  = (1/2)e^{\frac{1}{2}(x-ik)^2}\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x-ik)^2\cdot  = (x-ik)e^{\frac{1}{2}(x-ik)^2}$$
$$\frac{d}{dk}(e^{\frac{1}{2}(x-ik)^2}) = (1/2)e^{\frac{1}{2}(x-ik)^2}\frac{d}{dk}(x-ik)^2 = (-i)(x-ik)e^{\frac{1}{2}(x-ik)^2}$$

Now note that

$$\frac{d}{dx}(e^{\frac{1}{2}(x-ik)^2}) = (-i)\frac{d}{dk}(e^{\frac{1}{2}(x-ik)^2})$$

Iterate this $m \in \mathbb{N}$ times. The proof continues using induction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
For every analytic function $f(z)$ we have
$$f'(z)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}=-i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$
with induction prove 
$$\dfrac{\partial^m}{\partial x^m}f=(-i)^m\dfrac{\partial^m}{\partial y^m}f$$
now let $f(z)=e^{\frac12z^2}$.

Comment: [Cauchy-Riemann equations in complex form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Interpretation_and_reformulation)! Very nice. I would never thought this. (+1)